# how use graphvis in C# application?

Tags: c#, graphviz

i have a dot format file and i download graphvis for windows now
how can i use graphvis to show a graph in my c# application?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VDS.RDF;
using VDS.RDF.Parsing;
using VDS.RDF.Query;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using VDS.RDF.Writing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class first : Form

    {

         Graph g = new Graph();
         string s1 = null;

/**************************************DATA********************************************/
        public first()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Stream myStream = null;

            var parser = new Notation3Parser();
            var graph = new Graph();
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "RDF files (*.n3)|*.n3";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (myStream)
                        {
                            string s = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
                            string w= Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString();
                            string Fname = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.ToString();
                            File.Copy(s,Path.Combine(w,Fname),true);

                            // Insert code to read the stream here.
                            Win32.AllocConsole();
                            s1 = Path.Combine(w, Fname);
                            insertNodeButton.Visible = true;
                            delBut.Visible = true;
                            simi.Visible = true;
                            showNodes showNodes1 = new showNodes(s1);
                            g = showNodes1.returngraph();

                           Console.Read();
                           Win32.FreeConsole();
                          // g.SaveToFile("firstfile.n3");

                           this.Show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            GraphVizWriter hi = new GraphVizWriter();
            hi.Save(g, "c:\\ahmad.dot");

        }
```

this is my code i want to visul ahmad.dot file format to show a graph with graphvis or some sipmle class to show dot file format in png format

Comment: There is way too much going on here for us to know how to help you in your specific problem. You'll have to find a way to narrow it down so we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used simple code to launch dot.exe like so in the past:

```
private static string GenDiagramFile(string pathToDotFile)
{
    var diagramFile = pathToDotFile.Replace(".dot", ".png");

    ExecuteCommand("dot", string.Format(@"""{0}"" -o ""{1}"" -Tpng", 
                 pathToDotFile, diagramFile));

    return diagramFile;
}

private static void ExecuteCommand(string command, string @params)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(command, @params) {CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false });
}
```

If you don't mind a little quick-and-dirty approach, this may work for you

Comment: @ghasedak- tell me what you do want. You can use the `GenDiagramFile` function code to generate an image (`.png`, e.g.) and show that on a dialog/control. This _is_ what you want, not?

Comment: @ghasedak-: my friend, I have shown that full code as well. In all honesty, I think you'd just write `ExecuteCommand("dot", string.Format(@"""{0}"" -o ""{1}"" -Tpng", dotfile, diagramFile))` where `dotfile` is the path to your own, existing, dotfile

Comment: @ghasedak-: see my previous comment, especially the usage of the word `dotfile`

Comment: I've simplified my answer so you can see more clearly the information that was already there :) Also, please, refrain from shouting. It doesn't motivate me.

Comment: @ghasedak-: yeah. Did you try it?